# Best way to handle lazy models with mapstruct and spring transnational scope

Tags: java, architecture, spring, hibernate, jpa

In a typical Java Spring Web APP:

we have the following layers:

Model [DB Models]

Repositories [where you have queries to DB]

Services [Business service where you have the @Transactional annotation]

Controllers [Rest endpoints]

So for a simple model e.g Car

```
@Entity
Car {
   Long id;
   String name;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) // Notice lazy here
   Engine engine;
}

CarRepo extends JpaRepository {....}

@Transactional
CarService {
 ....
}

@RestController
CarController{
  @GET
  public CarDto getCar(Long id) {
      ???
  }
}
```

??? : Here is the big dilemma, I use a mapstruct to convert objects to other formats, whenever I use it as in first following scenario I get `LazyInitializationException`:

**Scenario#1** Get the model in controller (Which is not so good to do especially that models should be encapsulated from the view layer) and convert it to CarDto

```
CarController{
      @GET
      public CarDto getCar(Long id) {
          Car car= carService.getCar(id);
          return carMapper.toCarDto(car); // BAM `LazyInitializationException`, on `Engine` field!!! 
      }
    }
```

But here the problem, When mapper starts to convert `Engine` it will get `LazyInitializationException` since transaction was already committed and closed in service and `Engine` is lazy initialized

That moves us to **Scenario#2**
Ok so do the conversions in service then daa! while you still have the transaction opened, in service, so update the `getCar` method to return a `CarDto` instead:

```
  @Transactional
  CarService {
       CarDto getCar(Long id) {.... return mapper.toCarDto(car);} // Hurrah!!, no lazy exceptions since there is a transnational context wrapping that method
    }
```

But here is another problem, for other services in that uses `Car` suppose we have `FactoryService` and we want to get a car by id so that we can assign it to a factory model so we will diffidently need the `Car` model not the dto,

```
FactoryService {
    void createFactory() { 
      Factory factory = ....;
      Car car = carService.getCarModel...
      factory.addCar(car);
    }
}
```

so simple solution to this is to add another method with different name but will return model that time in the `CarService`

```
@Transactional
    CarService {
       CarDto getCar(Long id) {.... return mapper.toCarDto(car);}
       Car getCarModel(Long id) {.... return car;}
    }
```

But as you can see it is now ugly! to have the same function twice with same logic only with 2 different return types, that will also lead to have aloooot of same type logic method across the services

Eventually we have **Scenario#3** and that is simply use **Solution#1** but move the @Transactional annotation to the controller now we won't get the lazy exception when we use mapstruct in controller (But this is not very recommended thing to do since we are taking controlling transactions out of the service (business) layer)

```
@Transactional
CarController{
      @GET
      public CarDto getCar(Long id) {
          ???
      }
    
    }
```

So what would be the best approach to follow here

Comment: Making a whole service @Transactional doesn't seem (to me) the way to go. Usually, some methods are others are not. `get****` usually are not.

Comment: @Laiv Well, I just wanted to simplify the code in the post but usually, what I do is to have a Read Only transactional services e.g `CarReadService` annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` and a read/write transactional write service `CarWriteService` annotated by `@Transactional`

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that fetching the data from the DB for querying doesn't need to be transactional. Just provide CarReadService with non-modifier methods. That should be enough to ensure that nobody uses CarReadService to write/update the DB. Anyways, If the Service is only acting as a gateway to the repository, just call the repository from the Controller. Repositories are high level abstractions

Comment: In Java with Spring it does, every call to DB should be wrapped into a Transaction context, this keeps connections to DB properly managed by the application container (Spring)

Comment: Not true. Well, at least I never did so and I had no issues of DB access. Transactions are a business concept, not a technical requirement imposed by the framework

Comment: Well I found there is a big discussion about that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/818131/1460591

Comment: In a nutshell, you must define the boundaries of the business transaction, not everything in the business layer falls within a business transaction.

Comment: Usually all of my services are DB operations, but I see your point that maybe I would have a service that communicates with a 3rd party on that case I don't need a transaction that was provided by the annotation on the class, I can see this would be better to have it on the method

but apart from that, what I'm digging here about is the lazy exception vs mappers

Comment: Well, you have (at least) 2 easy solutions. #1, the service itself fetch all the lazy data before return. #2, Controller gets the data as is from the service and do perform a second call to the repository/service asking for all the data. Or just attach the entity to a new session and fetch the remaining data. When I go #2, my transactional methods do return a reference to the entity. The whole entity should be retrieved by a second query. Ofc it's contextual, if I can afford 2 calls I do, if not, the business service becomes a little bit more complex (#1).

Comment: #1 is pretty much what in Scenario#1 but problem here is that I will end up with having 2 methods one that returns a dto (used by controllers) and another that returns model (used by other services)

Comment: `Ofc it's contextual, if I can afford 2 calls I do, if not, the business service becomes a little bit more complex` exactly I was stressing that the service will end up having alot of methods some of them do the exact logic but with different returns or arguments

Comment: The solution #2 is similar to Scenario#3 I have in post, but what you are suggesting is different since yours would be creating couple of different transactions but same idea  but opening more connections/TX is not an option IMO

Comment: Because you want the controller to interact, solely, with the service. You still can make calls to the repository. Spring provide several Repository Interfaces (crud, query, criteria, etc). Some of them can be casted as read-only once injected in the controller. Or make your own read-only interface and use Spring Data

Comment: Yeah I see, but if you read about it more, it is a very bad idea to open a transaction outside the business layer, as some developers suggest to always encapsulate transactions open/close in business layer since it is a pricey operation to do you have to manage it from one place, and I totally agree with that TBH

Comment: I might be touching a technology limitation but I posted that Q in order to gather more info how other developers deal with that situation

Comment: I have upvoted the question because now I'm interested in how other developers solve this.

Comment: Thanks that was a pretty good discussion +1

Answer (score 1):

The first scenario seems a good approach. By default, the method `getCar` should just return the `Car` object without the `Engine` (as it is set to be fetched lazily). If the controller needs the `Car` and the `Engine`, an option is to provide an additional method `CarService#getCarWithEngine`. Such a method, will explicitly load and return the `Car` with the `Engine` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7567658/8484783)). This can be done in many ways, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-initialize-proxy-exception).
For example, as suggested in the linked tutorial, you can create a method in `CarRepo` that uses Join Fetching:

```
public interface CarRepo extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Car c JOIN FETCH c.engine")
    Optional<Car> findCarByIdWithEngine(Long id);
}
```

This method can then be used by `CarService#getCarWithEngine` (with or without @Transactional) to implement scenario 1. Mapping the entity to the DTO in the controller layer keeps the service layer independent of the particular request so that it can be better reused and tested. Such an approach is also suggested [here](https://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).

Scenario 2 makes `CarService` dependent on the DTO, which (as you have demonstrated) is not ideal. A new API that needs a different view of the `Car`, or even a slightly different response in the controller layer, will require `CarService` to change.

An additional approach is to keep the session open with `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true`, so that Hibernate can resolve lazy associations even after returning from an explicit @Transactional service. More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view#lazy-initialization-hero).

There are more than one solution, it depends on the abstraction level that you need for your project, and if the additional complexity is worth it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, For `CarService#getCarWithEngine` I like this but doing this for all models could be a pretty damn job to cover all view scenarios and also will pollute the service imagine that we have 
`withEngine`
`withEngineAndManufacturer`
`withEngineAndManufacturerWithOriginCountry` 
however I would think that this would be the best approach yet I can think of right now at least it will avoid issuing the query to load the lazy field since on that case it will be returned by the original query

Comment: For `spring.jpa.open-in-view=true` the OSIV is considered an Anti-Pattern check 
@Vlad Mihalcea answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37526397/1460591

Comment: @YouYou I am glad I could help. I see that there are [a lot of discussions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7107) about OSIV. Even though it's considered an anti-pattern by many it's enabled by default in Spring Boot (with a warning). So I listed it as an additional approach since in [some use cases](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view#choose-wisely) can still be relevant.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought you might not know that, since I have just know it recently